# Append Tee & Boot to Existing Branch ( flexible duct) to Split supply between floors

Tags: hvac

I have a space in finish basement where I have to supply heat from ceiling. But in ceiling, in some places, main supply trunk is not reachable or some occupied by other vent for upstairs. Now I am ending up with reuse the existing branch of 7" flexible duct, which goes up stairs currently. I think I just have add a tee and then attach boot. I know cons of splitting the supply.

I need to know what register vent boot, do I have to use which is compatible with duct tee or How do i achieve this ?

The joists in ceiling running 16 inch center and 2 in. x 10 in. in size.
The floor space in basement is 180 sqft

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Clear, focused, well lit pictures of the areas in question, along with dimensions (have someone hold a tape measure up in the pic on a key dimension, others can be estimated from there) will help _immeasurably_!

Answer (score 1):

Splitting that 7" flex duct to two ducts will yield very little heat to either room. I would find another "tap-in" spot off the main trunk to get heat for the basement. Can you add a supply register to the bottom of the supply trunk.

A picture or two would help us understand what you want to accomplish, what problems you are encountering, and what options we see that would resolve this problem.

Comment: I like the idea of adding supply register to the bottom of the main trunk. but it close to return. I'll post a picture soon. thanks